# How can you use PowerShell's . (dot) notation to walk through elements with periods in the element name?

Tags: xml, powershell

PowerShell makes working with XML fairly easy in most cases. However, I'm having trouble using the "dot" notation to walk through a web.config file. Everything works

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$site = get-website | ? { $_.name -eq "My Website - 80" }
$WebConfigFile = $site.physicalPath + "\web.config"
[xml]$WebAppXml = Get-Content $WebConfigFile
$webAppXml.configuration.system.web
```

On the last line, PowerShell uses intellisense to fill in system.web, but if you try to run it, the output is null. I know I can use Xpath or the .NET Xml objects, but I'd rather not if I don't have to.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
$webAppXml.configuration.'system.web'
```

Answer (score 4):

This works too:

e.g.

```
$webAppXml.configuration.["system.web"].Identity
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use variables:

```
$subproperty = 'System.Web'
$webAppXml.configuration.$subproperty
```

I find this to be the most useful technique, because it lets me switch properties easily.

BTW, you can use the same trick to get to a method definition, and not run it.

Hope this Helps