# Accessing complex properties like "system.serviceModel" when using Powershell to parse xml

Tags: xml, powershell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you use PowerShell's . (dot) notation to walk through elements with periods in the element name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526865/how-can-you-use-powershells-dot-notation-to-walk-through-elements-with-perio)

I know that powershell will add properties to XmlElements to simplify accessing the elements and attributes.

When parsing a web.config, you get elements like 'system.serviceModel".

When a pass the XmlElement to Get-member, I can see that this is a property, but when I try to access the property I get an error message.

I assume that it is because the engine is looking for a property called system who has a property called serviceModel and not a property called "system.serviceModel"

What would be the best way to parse and access these elements?

Comment: There have been many questions like this. Wish people read the suggestions before posting questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have a web.config file to parse right now, but if I understand the problem it is that in the file there exists a node with the name system.servicemodel. To access a node like that you just quote it. So if you have a variable $xml that represented the parent of that node, you could access it via:

$xml.'system.servicemodel'

Comment: Forgot that there was a web.config in just about every folder in any .net framework install (or it seems that way at least). So I checked and as I say if I understand the issue then this works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew it had to be something simple